# How lazy evaluation in django query works?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm having doubt regarding lazy evaluation in django-querysets.

This is my django query:

**Method1:**

`tyres_in_car = Car.objects.filter(serial_no__startswith('AB')).values('tyre__type')`

In this query I'm accessing foreign key values using `.values()` (tyre type) in this case.

Another approach which I use is:

**Method2:**

Line1 : `tyres = Car.objects.filter(serial_no__startswith('AB'))`

Line2 : `all_tyres = tyres.tyre.all()`

Line3 : `tyres_in_car = [ ty.type for ty in all_tyres ]`

Since, I'm using `.values()` in both the methods, does the query hits database only once in both the cases( because of lazy evaluation in case of Method 2) or it hits two times in case of Method 2.

From the perspective of code readability, Method 2 looks more appropriate in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a while over various posts, I wasn't clearly able to reach upon any of the solution.

So, I've decided to profile queries myself.

The generated query for **Method1** is a single query :

`SELECT "I_tyre"."type" FROM "I_car" LEFT OUTER JOIN "I_car_tyre" ON ("I_car"."id" = "I_car_tyre"."car_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "I_tyre" ON ("I_car_tyre"."tyre_id" = "I_tyre"."id") WHERE "I_car"."id" = 1  LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'`

And for **Method2** are 2 queries :

query1 : `'SELECT "I_car"."id", "I_car"."serial_no" FROM "I_car" WHERE "I_car"."id" = 1'`

query2 : `'SELECT "I_tyre"."id", "I_tyre"."type" FROM "I_tyre" INNER JOIN "I_car_tyre" ON ("I_tyre"."id" = "I_car_tyre"."tyre_id") WHERE "I_car_tyre"."car_id" = 1'`

Answer (score 0):

The better way than both is to query Tyres in the first place.

```
Tyre.objects.filter(car__serial_no__startswith='AB').values('type')
```

Comment: Yes!, but consider if I need to fetch values from car table also.